# Rotating a table in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice

Alright, so I've got a table which is a lot wider than its length. And I want it on a page on LibreOffice Writer. It doesn't fit as it is, width-wise/horizontally, which is what I want to do. So I've tried two things:

1- Insert->Frame->Frame->Options->Properties->Right to Left (Vertical) [to try and have it fit the page vertically]

2- Landscaping the page to fit it horizontally

The first option messes up the table and formatting itself, I don't want it wrapped in a "frame". The second option does not only NOT fit it horizontally in the page, but also leaves out a lot of unnecessary page space. I don't want to take table's screenshot and add as image, as that is not consistent with other tables in the paper. Ideally, I'd like to simply rotate the table as the folks using MS word do. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The steps will allow to rotate it like in MS Word (in reality, it just changes the text orientation)

1. Select the table.
2. Right click,then select `Table Properties`.
3. Change the Text Orientation.
4. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I often take a table with too many columns into Excel and transpose it, then paste it back into word.